# How to deserialize oData V2 with JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json, odata

I am trying to deserialize oData V2 with C#, but Value is allways null:

```
    {
    "d": {
        "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
            "id": "http://vhcalnplci:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZEMPLOYEE_SRV/EmployeeEntitySet('111111')",
            "uri": "http://vhcalnplci:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZEMPLOYEE_SRV/EmployeeEntitySet('111111')",
            "type": "ZEMPLOYEE_SRV.EmployeeEntity"
            },
            "Empno": "111111",
            "Fname": "Test Firstname",
            "Lname": "Test Lastname",
            "Addrs": "Test Address",
            "Desgn": "Test Job"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried CLR Class Generation in Visual Studio, and created the following classes

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public D d { get; set; }
    }

    public class D
    {
        public Result[] results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public __Metadata __metadata { get; set; }
        public string Empno { get; set; }
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string Lname { get; set; }
        public string Addrs { get; set; }
        public string Desgn { get; set; }
    }

    public class __Metadata
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uri { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    internal class OData<Result>
    {
        public List<Result> Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Method I've used where Result is always zero

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
     var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OData<Employee>>(json);
     var employee = result.Value;
 }
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `OData<Employee>` be `OData<Result>`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Not really - the `OData<T>` class isn't even relevant to the JSON (there's no `Value` property anywhere). The only logical way is with `DeserializeObject<Root>` - but the OP claims the result is the same, which makes me think there's something else not shown here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yeah that's where I was trying to go - it's not even relevant but I wasn't sure if the code even compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OData<Employee>>(json);
```

into

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also tried Rootobject and Result, but there is also result "null"

Comment: Thanks var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json); worked!

Comment: @InzinjerIzBosne Oops It's my bad, it's not Root, according to your class it should be `Rootobject`. ANyway happy to help you.